# Azure App service can't start because it can't find swagger documentation xml using ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

**Update 2:** The file does not get published. That is what is wrong. However, I can't figure out why one of my computers can publish it the right way and the other doesn't after the Visual studio upgrade.

**Update**: Running the same solution on two different computers where the APIProject.xml file get's correctly published from one computer but not the other there are now only one difference left. The computer from which the publishing works runs the not updated version of Visual studio 2017 Enterprise. 15.5.2 does not work and 15.4.2 works.

I'm getting this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\APIProject.xml'.

The file is placed in bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0 
It works locally but when published to Azure App service it crashes.

I'm publishing to the staging slot I created and haven't tried production yet. Publishing replaces all files at destination.

Here is my setup of Swagger but it used to work :)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Ecommerce/Product API",
                Description = "Handles API based shopping functionality",
                TermsOfService = "Terms of service should be contracted with inidividually",
                Contact = new Contact { Name = "Magnus", Email = "magnus@secret", Url = "" },
                License = new License { Name = "Use under permission from our Group", Url = "http://aboutno" }
            });

            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "APIProject.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });   
    }
```

What has changed is I added the "UseSetting"-row in Program.cs to get errors of why it doesn't start. Before adding that row I did't get developer error, only got end user error page.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

I'm trying to publish with Debug mode. Also tried with Release as of one answer below but no difference.

I checked out the code in another computer and publishing from that computer works so the problem just got more weird to me!

Answer (score 20):

My *.Net Core 2.0* app worked fine locally, but threw a pointless "**An error occurred while starting the application.**" error when deployed to Azure.

Checking the logs, the cause was that Swagger couldn't find a particular .xml file  (why the hell doesn't the error message let us know ?!)

The solution was to select the Build tab, change the Configuration drop down list to "Release", then tick this box:

[image]

That's it.

For some reason, by default it was ticked (with the .xml filename filled in) for Debug, but not for Release.

(Sigh.)

Comment: This was the case for me.  Thanks for the find.

Comment: This solved it for me as well - I didn't realize this setting was per each configuration. I just want to note that I needed to make sure the value of "Output path" was changed to match what I had in other configuration(s). The automatically filled in value when "Xml documentation file" was checked was not correct for me.

Comment: That dejà vú moment when you come here and you see you have already upvoted this solution...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the equivalent block exists in the csproj file in the Debug as well as the Release mode. I guess you are publishing the release mode.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\APIProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It have <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\APIProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: sure, but what about the release mode?  isn't it what you are publishing? you need to make sure that the xml file is generated in the release mode

Comment: besides, make sure the same file name as referenced  in c# code

Comment: I'm trying to release the debug version to stage, sorry should have been clear about that. Added one for Release and set the publish to release but same error. Updated question with more information

Comment: is this file being published? do you see it in kudu?

Comment: Yes, I can see it here using kudo. D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0>

Comment: Well, yes and no, I thought the error was that App Service was looking for the file in the wrong directory. Now I know better. How do I get my file to the right directory? The other files listed in the same folder are all there but this xml file is not.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue today when published ASP.NET Core Web Application powered by .NET Core 2.1 to Azure App Service.

It worked locally fine when running in Debug mode, but failed in Release. The reason was because I didn’t have the following config section in the `*.csproj` file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\OneGit.Api.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Which is represent the checkbox `XML documentation file` in the section `Build` => `Output` when right-click on a project and select menu-item `Properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing publish configuration from release to debug solved my problem. 
[image]